# Prove that there are infinitely many intermediate field of $K=k(x,y)$ over $F=k(x^p,y^p)$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many intermediate field of $K=k(x,y)$ over $F=k(x^p,y^p)$.

I know $[K:F]=p^2$

and my intution is the intermediate fields are of the form $L=F(a)$ for some $a \in K-F$. I think $a_n$ will some of the form $x+y^n$ then $L_n=F(a_n)$..

Now how to show this easily?

Comment: As I recall, the trick that works for $k$ infinite is to take $a=y+\lambda x$ for $\lambda\in k$

Comment: If $F(y+\lambda x)=F(y+\mu x)$ for $\lambda \neq \mu$ then how to show $y,x \in  F(y+\mu x)$? I am taking $y+\lambda x=$ some polynomial in $y+\mu x$, but can't cancel out..

Comment: If $y+\lambda x$ and $y+\mu x$ both are in a field, then so are $y$ and $x$, so in this case, the field is $F(x,y)$. Easy as that.