# If $\text{char}(k)=p$, $K=k(x,y), F=k(x^p,y^p)$, then $[K:F]=P^2$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I get the result from this post
[Prove that there are infinitely many intermediate field of $K=k(x,y)$ over $F=k(x^p,y^p)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511659/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-intermediate-field-of-k-kx-y-over-f-k)

Assume we already have result

> If $\theta\in K\setminus F$, then $[F(\theta): F]=p$

Let $h(t)=t-\theta\in F(\theta)[t]$. It has root in $K$ and clearly irreducible, hence $[K:F(\theta)]=\deg(h)=1$ and hence $[L:F]=[L:F(\theta)][F(\theta):F]=p$. I don't really see where I went wrong in the proof. Can anyone point it out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $[k(x,y):k(x^p,y^p)]=p^2$, we can argue as follows . . .

Consider the chain of fields
$$
k(x^p,y^p) \subset k(x^p,y) \subset k(x,y)
\qquad\qquad\;\;\;
$$
Since $p$ is prime, and the inclusions are proper, it follows that 
$$
\begin{cases}
[k(x,y):k(x^p,y)]=p
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\,
\\[4pt]
[k(x^p,y):k(x^p,y^p)]=p\\
\end{cases}
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
&[k(x,y):k(x^p,y^p)]\\[4pt]
&=[k(x,y):k(x^p,y)]\cdot[k(x^p,y):k(x^p,y^p)]\\[4pt]
&=p\cdot p\\[4pt]
&=p^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
As regards your error . . .

You don't know that $F(\theta)=K$, so the fact that $\theta$ has degree $1$ over $F(\theta)$ doesn't prove $[K:F(\theta)]=1$.

Thus, from the fact that $\theta \in K$, and $t-\theta$ is irreducible in $F(\theta)[t]$, all you get is $[F(\theta):F(\theta)]=1$, which tells you nothing about $[K:F]$.

Comment: Thanks! I indeed messed up K and $F(\theta)$.